# How can I get sendmail to drop messages instead of retrying them?

Tags: email, sendmail

We have a server that collects email alert messages. We use sendmail on a Linux system to send the alert messages to that server. Sometimes that server is down for maintenance and we do not care if the alert messages are not collected. Is there a way to configure sendmail to try delivery one time and then drop/delete a message if it cannot be delivered?

Currently sendmail just queues the messages for delivery. The queues can get very large if the server is down for a long while. So we would rather just delete the queued messages automatically.